# How can I prove these?

Tags: linear-algebra

I got 3 statements to prove if they are true

$i)$ $\dim(\Bbb C)=1$

$ii)$ $\dim(\Bbb R(i))=\dim(\Bbb C)\rightarrow \Bbb R(i)=\Bbb C$

$iii)$ $\dim(\Bbb Q(\sqrt2))= \dim (\Bbb R)\rightarrow  \Bbb Q(\sqrt2)=\Bbb R$

i) is obviously wrong if R is the base $\dim(\Bbb C)=2$

iii) isnt this equation always wrong? $\dim(\Bbb Q(\sqrt2))=\dim (\Bbb R)$

Comment: dim over what field?

Comment: it didnt specify the bases. it was a multiple choice question

Comment: Well, for iii)  *IF* dim(Q (root 2)) = dim(R) [which it doesn't] then Q(root (2)) = R.  Which it doesn't but it *would* if the hypothesis where true.  I have to review dim before I can comment but off hand these are contradictory.  i) may be true.  ii) says  "if i) is true than a true statement"; that's certainly possible.  iii) says "if a statement that is probably false is true than a false statement would be true"; which is possible.

Comment: Okay.  dim C = 2 as a vector space over R.  But dim C = 1 as vector space over C.  So it would seem we are supposed to view these as vector spaces over C.  Um, remind me if a vector space can be a proper subset of the field it is over?  I assume not?

Comment: thanks for your comment. so over any field $\dim(\Bbb Q(\sqrt2))\neq \dim (\Bbb R)$ right? @fleablood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ii) it's obvious that $\mathbb{R}(i)$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of degree 2 also $\mathbb{R}(i)\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $dim(\mathbb{C})=2$ so you have the equality $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}(i)$

iii)obviosly that equation is always wrong because of : $dim(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=2$ and $dim(\mathbb{R})=1$

Comment: technically, that makes statement iii) true!  As the hypothesis if false, the conclusion can be false.  The statement "F -> F" is always true.  Technically speaking.

Comment: Yes you are all right, I suppose he was asking about the truth of the hypotesis. Obviously hypotesis false make all the assertion true